# cp large file to /dev/null to reduce size to zero

Tags: files, filesystems, cp, null

I just came across the advice that if you want to get rid of a large file and a process has the file handle open you should copy it to /dev/null and its size will be reduce to zero.

How does this work? Or does this even work?

After a quick search I found conflicting answers ranging from "Yes, this totally works" to " Your whole machine is going to blow up". Can somebody enlighten me?

I found the question here:
https://syedali.net/engineer-interview-questions/

Comment: Where did you find the advice?  I can't see how doing `cp big_file /dev/null` would modify `big_file` in any way (well, perhaps its atime), and especially not how it would 0 out the file

Comment: I found it in this blog about potential interview questions: https://syedali.net/engineer-interview-questions/

Comment: Ah, note that you got the direction of copying wrong, that page says "you can ‘cp /dev/null’ on the file" which is the opposite of copying your file to `/dev/null`

Comment: Ah, true i got that wrong. That makes more sense. So nevermind my question and thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misread the advice, the idea is not to copy the large file to `/dev/null`, which wouldn't affect it in any way, outside putting it in cache if space is available.

```
cp bigfile /dev/null # useless
```

The advice is not to remove the file then copy `/dev/null` to it, as it would keep the original inode unchanged and won't free any disk space as long as processes have that file open.

The advice is to replace the file content with `/dev/null` one, which, given the fact `/dev/null` size is zero by design, is effectively truncating the file to zero bytes:

```
cp /dev/null bigfile # works

cat /dev/null > bigfile # works
```

It might be noted that if you use a shell to run these commands, there is no need to use `/dev/null`, a simple empty redirection will have the same effect and would be more efficient, `cat /dev/null` being a no-op anyway.

```
: > bigfile # better

> bigfile  # even better if the shell used supports it
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, it doesn't work.

There are many flavour of unix abroad, may be for *some* this might work, can you provide a link ?

Now, you can test it:

1. open two terminal in your system.
2. copy to non root user a large file (like  `/var/log/messages` )
3. vi it ( `vi messages` ) in first terminal.
4. `cp messages /dev/null` on other.
5. quit vi on first.

`messages` should still be there.

(vi is not a good candidate, if you remove file, (`rm messages`) file will be removed (at least on ubuntu 16.04), you can rewrite it from vi (using <kbd>w</kbd> but file will be read from `.messages.swp` on current dir)

Comment: No, `cp messages /dev/null` cannot possibly truncate `messages`. (Well, sure, it's physically possible, but if a system erases data when told to copy it, it's severely broken.)